# Correct Activity/Fragment Architecture for Android Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I would like to get some input on the best way to structure my app's architecture when using Android's Bottom Navigation View.

Currently I define my `BottomNavigationView` in my MainActivity. It looks something like this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.action_home:
                        selectedFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
                        break;

                    case R.id.action_search:
                        selectedFragment = SearchFragment.newInstance();
                        break;

                    case R.id.action_message:
                        selectedFragment = MessageFragment.newInstance();
                        break;

                    case R.id.action_profile:
                        selectedFragment = ProfileFragment.newInstance();
                        break;
                }

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }
        });

        //Manually displaying the first fragment - one time only
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, HomeFragment.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();

    }
```

The problem is that once I click on one tab, it opens up a fragment, and I would like to have those Fragments open up other Fragments/Activities (i.e:

1. I open the profile tab (`ProfileFragment` loads)
2. I click on a button from `ProfileFragment`, and from this the `SignUpFragment` or `SignUpActivity` loads

After running into many bugs, I've researched on how to architect my app, but i've found mixed results. Would anyone know the correct way of using a `BottomNavigationView` with `Fragments`, and in those `fragments` I can load more `Activities/fragments`. A huge thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Every approach depends on the project and what you pretend to achieve. I had to code a Bottom Navigation app that works with over 20 Bottom Navigation layouts, meaning one single Activity. The process you wish to achieve is pretty much the same of setting the desired fragment in the desired tab on tab selected, the difference is that, instead of taping on a tab, you will tap on a button inside a fragment, which you will replace with the new desired fragment.

tap tab -> replace fragment -> button click inside fragment -> replace fragment -> and so on.

Since you are using replace, you will have to carefully handle your `onBackPress` event, since I'm assuming that on every back press you wish to go back to the previous fragment. Myself, I've implemented an interface in the Main Activity that listens to the visible fragment onBackPress.